# Choose all files from a folder - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I need to read all images from a folder `test_image`, to do so, all the images have to have same prefixes in name.

```
PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'test_images'
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'image{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 21) ]
```

I want to choose another folder. How can I do this without changing all the names into that format?

Comment: You may use `os.listdir()`  to get the list of all the file names in a given directory.

Comment: Use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import glob, os

PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'dir'
searchstr = os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, '*.jpg')
list_of_images = glob.glob(searchstr)
```

using glob, assuming that you're just looking for all the .jpg files.